# error while using jQuery UI Autocomplete in TypeScript

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, typescript

I am using  jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.16 in TypeScript, Its giving me error

Unhandled exception at line 303, column 3 in http:/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Autocomplete is using

- jquery.ui.core.js
- jquery.ui.widget.js
- jquery.ui.position.js

i am including definition files which i downloaded from internet

```
<reference path="../jquery.d.ts" />
<reference path="../jqueryui.d.ts" /> its version is jQueryUI 1.9
```

not sure its a version conflict or what.Can you please tell me how i can fix that.

My autocomplete code in TypeScript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
    $("#FileCode").autocomplete({
        source: this.GetFileCodes,           
        minLength: 3,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                $("#FilCode").val(ui.item.value);
                $("form").submit();
            }
        }
    });
});

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Steve your question gave me clue.

I debug and found source was empty

```
source: this.GetFileCodes
```

once i add hard coded URL it worked.then i fixed my source url path and its worked.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiles okay so the most likely cause of your issue is that you haven't included the JavaScript files at runtime:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually my actual .js file is working fine, i am implementing TypeScript from scretch and replacing .ts generated .js with actual one, means my ols one was abc.js and i just created abc1.ts and replaced by abc1.js in aspx page. so this should not be issue, also i verified all of these references are there in site.Master.If you need some additional info let me know i can provide code if you want.

Comment: The error you posted looks like a runtime error... What do you have around line 303 in the autocomplete js file?

Comment: here is function where error is coming in jquery.ui.autocomplete.js _search: function( value ) {
  this.pending++;
  this.element.addClass( "ui-autocomplete-loading" );

  this.source( { term: value }, this.response );
 }, saying source is null.

Comment: Thanks Steve you question gave me clue, actually source was empty once i add hard coded URL it worked.Thanks alot